# R/vba - Open and save several workbooks (+500) and discarding formulas ie. keeping only dataframe

Tags: r, excel, xlconnect, vba

I would like to open several workbook files (xlsx), with multiple spreadsheets, discard the formulas in each cell and only keeping the data inside. I would do it mannualy but with at least 500 workbooks i would like to automise the task.

I found myself multiple partial solutions. Maybe the most simple one would be to do it via vba, but i have no idea how to write those instructions. The other solutions i could manage would be through R.

I tested several packages, the most usefull being xlsx, unfortunatelly i can only save 1 spreadsheed at a time, and i have more than 15 per workbook, and i didnt find how to combine each spreadsheet in one file (one workbook).

The solution i came so far is to open files inside a loop, then save them again with XLConnect. I searched for a write-without-formula, knowing that open-without-formula exists, but i didn't manage to find the option ... Is there a simple solution with those packages or should i go more into VBA ?

tentative in r :

```
library("XLConnect")
wbdir <- setwd("C:/Users/blabla/Desktop/wbfiles")
wblist <- list.files(wbdir)

i <- 0L
for (i in 1:length(wblist)) {

        wb_formulas <- loadWorkbook(wblist[[i]])
        # something to overwriteformulas : opening witout formulas like xlsx/openxlsx package 
        # writing without ...
        wb_df <- saveWorkbook(wb_formulas, paste(c("wb_", i,".xlsx"),collapse = ""))
}
```

Comment: VBA can easily do this, and you can also do this without opening the documents. Excel can read them as a "read-only" file... I did a quick good search and this is a great resource to get you started http://www.encodedna.com/excel/copy-data-from-closed-excel-workbook-without-opening.htm

Comment: I would use vba.  break the tasks down.  loop through the books,  then run a function which opens, copies the information, pastes to other book, then closes the sample book.  You could very well use r though.

Comment: Please post code of what you already tried

Comment: edited

edited

@Maldred checking the links, i'll try to check some easy VBA code also if couldnt avoid this part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider R's `RDComclient` which can [COM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680573(v=vs.85).aspx) interface to the Excel object library where you can use R to loop through needed files and corresponding worksheets and use Excel's own methods (not third-party package methods), [Range.Copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-copy-method-excel) and [Range.PasteSpecial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-pastespecial-method-excel), to copy cell values,  leaving out formulas.

Below procedure is wrapped in a `tryCatch` to cleanly exit the processing even with simple errors. Do note: some `COMExceptions` are not caught and you will need to exit the EXCEL.EXE process from Task Manager.

```
library(RDCOMClient)

wbdir <- setwd("C:/Users/blabla/Desktop/wbfiles")
wblist <- list.files(wbdir, full.names = TRUE)

xlPasteValues <- -4163

for (wb in wblist) {    
  tryCatch({
    # Create COM Connection to Excel
    xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
    xlApp[['Visible']] <- FALSE
    xlApp[['DisplayAlerts']] <- FALSE

    # Open workbook
    xlWB <- xlApp[["Workbooks"]]$Open(wb)

    # Iterate through each worksheet
    for (s in seq(xlWB$Worksheets()$Count())) {
      xlSheet <- xlWB$Worksheets(s)

      # Copy and paste values
      xlSheet$Cells()$Copy() 
      xlSheet$Cells()$PasteSpecial(xlPasteValues)

      xlApp[['CutCopyMode']] <- FALSE

      xlSheet$Activate()
      xlSheet$Range("A1")$Select()        
    }

    }, error=function(e) {
        print(e)  
    },

    finally={
      xlApp[['DisplayAlerts']] <- TRUE

      # Save Changes
      xlWB$Close(TRUE)        # THIS WILL OVERWRITE (BACKUP IN TEST MODE)
      xlApp$Quit()

      # Release resources
      xlSheet <- NULL
      xlWB <- NULL
      xlApp <- NULL

      rm(list=ls()) 
      gc()
    }
  )    
}
```

*Since COM is a Windows technology, above solution only works in R running in Windows environments.*

Comment: Sorry, unwanted refresh ...

Thanks for this code Parfait, i'll try to catch up the RDComclient package. 

It works pretty well, nontheless i have a error which i don't understand why it appears sometimes : the clipboard message copy/paste thing. I searched and it should't appear with the xlApp[['cutcopymode']] <- False. Am I right ? It doesn't if cells are < 100

Comment: That's not an error but a user warning from Excel about the amount placed on clipboard. Does it keep popping up with each file or only once? Does R console show any error?

Comment: Indeed popping with each file and seems also to interrupt the copy. R console show this : "

<simpleError in xlSheet$Cells()$PasteSpecial(xlPasteValues): object 'xlPasteValues' not found>

Comment: See update disabling/enabling alerts with Excel's [DisplayAlerts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-displayalerts-property-excel) property. And be sure you have *xlPasteValues* (outside loop) assigned as this solution has it.

Comment: Thanks parfait. It's now working. I still had an error prompt but your last message give me a hint to correct it. I put the `xlPasteValues <- -4163` inside the first loop. I noticed that the variables were erased after the first iteration. Maybe this was the problem i had from the beginning. Anyway the code is now (if someone need that also) :
`library(RDCOMClient)
wbdir <- setwd("C:/Users/blabla/Desktop/wbfiles")
wblist <- list.files(wbdir, full.names = TRUE)
wblist
xlPasteValues <- (-4163)

for (wb in wblist) {
        xlPasteValues <- (-4163)`